# Dependency Injection via __construct() into Symfony/Doctrine EntityListener

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine, autowired, event-listener

i am struggeling with the following problem:

I created an EntityListener for one of my Entities.

```
namespace App\Event\EventListener\Vendor;

use App\Entity\Vendor;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class VendorListener
{
    private MessageBusInterface $messageBus;

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $messageBus)
    {
        $this->messageBus = $messageBus;
    }


    public function preUpdate(
        Vendor $vendor,
        PreUpdateEventArgs $args,
    ) {

        if ($args->hasChangedField('blacklistStatus')) {
            if ($args->getNewValue('blacklistStatus')) {
                //do something


            } 
        }
    }
}
```

In the respectice Entity i 'attached' it via annotations.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Event\EventListener\Vendor\VendorListener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: VendorRepository::class)]
#[ORM\EntityListeners([VendorListener::class])]
class Vendor
{

...
}
```

My service.yaml file looks as follows and as described in the official [docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineBundle/current/entity-listeners.html).

```
App\Event\EventListener\Vendor\VendorListener:
    tags:
        -
          name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener
          entity: App\Entity\Vendor
          event: preUpdate
```

The listener works and is triggered as expected, but only as long as i comment out the construct-method.
If i try to access some Service in the EntityListener via the constructor i get the following error-message displayed:

> Too few arguments to function App\Event\EventListener\Vendor\VendorListener::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bodensee\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Mapping\ContainerEntityListenerResolver.php on line 82 and exactly 1 expected

Am i missing something? Or is it just now possible to autowire services into the doctrine entityListeners since for some reason they are not initiated by symfony but by doctrine?

I have found an interesting [thread](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25003) talking about the problem i am having. Sadly the proposed solution is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
#[ORM\EntityListeners([VendorListener::class])]
```

This is the doctrine listener, not the symfony listener. Autowire works only for symfony listener.

You can create a listener which implements `Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber`. Without the `service.yaml` configuration and entity annotation `ORM\EntityListeners`.
Just only one class `VendorListener`

```
namespace App\EventListener\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class VendorListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    private MessageBusInterface $messageBus;

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $messageBus)
    {
        $this->messageBus = $messageBus;
    }


    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (!$args->getObject() instanceof Vendor) {
            return;
        }

        if ($args->hasChangedField('blacklistStatus')) {
            if ($args->getNewValue('blacklistStatus')) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::preUpdate => 'preUpdate',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your code works because Symfony and Doctrine use different event dispatchers.  Symfony can indeed autowire Doctrine listeners using attributes. https://symfony.com/doc/6.3/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-listeners

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works or me now:

Instead of attaching the EntityListener via annotations to the respective entity, such as

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: VendorRepository::class)]
#[ORM\EntityListeners([VendorListener::class])]
class Vendor
{

...
}
```

Configure the target entity in the EntityListener itself, as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-entity-listeners)

```
use App\Entity\Vendor;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Attribute\AsEntityListener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

#[AsEntityListener(event: Events::preUpdate, method: 'preUpdate', entity: Vendor::class)]
class VendorListener
{
...
}
```

With this, dependency injetion via constructor is possible. The reason seems to be that `ORM\EntityListeners()` are handled by doctrine itself, which leaves them without access to the container.

Comment: Just for info there are lifecycle callbacks, lifecycle listeners and entity listeners.  It is all too easy to get them mixed up which is why your original code did not work.  These are all [documented](https://symfony.com/doc/6.3/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-listeners) in Symfony as well.